# Is there a worldwide association for stunt/trick/tournament hang-gliding?

Tags: glider, unpowered, hang-glider, trainer

I'm wondering if there is any prevailing organized body of sports-people in hang-gliders, other gliders, and/or personal non-powered glide craft in general?

I'm particularly interested in stunts related to gliding, competitions, and how to find people in each locale (presumably) thorough an 'organized' body of sports-people.

Comment: [FAI's aerobatics committee](http://www.fai.org/aerobatics) might be a place to start. In general, FAI takes care of worldwide airsports matters.

Answer (score 2):

[FAI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A9d%C3%A9ration_A%C3%A9ronautique_Internationale) (Fédération Aéronautique Internationale)

> – The World Air Sports Federation, is the world governing body for air
>   sports, aeronautics and astronautics world records. Its head office is
>   in Lausanne, Switzerland.[3] This includes man-carrying aerospace
>   vehicles from balloons to spacecraft, and unmanned aerial vehicles
>   (such as model aircraft and UAVs). It was founded on 14 October 1905.

FAI is the international governing body for Acrobatics through its FAI Aerobatics Commission("Commission Internationale de Voltige Aerienne" – CIVA).

For Gliding through [FAI Gliding Commission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAI_Gliding_Commission)("International Gliding Commission – IGC").

For Hang Gliding and Paragliding through FAI Hang Gliding & Paragliding Commission ("Commission Internationale de Vol Libre – CIVL)

Answer (score 0):

I have learned of an organization that calls itself the [International Aerobatics Club](https://www.iac.org/).  It seems to be a US-based competition group, which prepares teams for international competitions.